# Do we really need to drop the foreign keys before drop the tables?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Migration**

```
def self.up
    create_table :test_drafts do |t|
      t.string :title, :limit => 255, :null => false
      t.text :description
      t.integer :user_id, :null => false
      t.integer :test_id, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_foreign_key(:test_drafts,:user_id,:users,:cascade)
    add_foreign_key(:test_drafts,:test_id,:tests,:cascade)
  end

  def self.down
    drop_foreign_key(:test_drafts,:user_id)
    drop_foreign_key(:test_drafts,:test_id)
    drop_table(:test_drafts)
  end
```

Do we really need to drop foreign keys before drops the tables ? 
Can I drop tables directly without drop foreign keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because of
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good practice for writing migration. There are few database which do not allow to drop table if there is any foreign key defined on it.

and as rails give you power to work on various databases so ideally its suggested to consider such best practices.

Answer (score 0):

It is dependency. Firstly, you should drop independent tables, even if they contain foreign keys.